# Calculating a limit with Riemann sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

My textbook has the following exercise I'm currently trying to complete:

Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{n^2 - k^2}$ with Riemann sums.

After playing with it for a bit I arrived at this:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{n^2 - k^2} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{n^2\left(1 - \frac{k^2}{n^2}\right)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \sqrt{1 - \frac{k^2}{n^2}}$$

From here on I didn't really know what to do and so I looked the solution up and it simply says, that this can be interpreted as the following integral:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$$

Solving this integral is easy, since its just a quarter of the unit circle and therefore evaluates to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, but I just don't really understand how the book simply arrived at this integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $f$ is Riemann integrable: $$\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac kn\right)$$
where the right side is the limit of Riemann sums.

When you have $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2},$ the right side is exactly what you got for your limit.

---

The integral from $a$ to $b$ is more complicated::

$$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx =\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(a+k\frac{b-a}n\right)$$

The reason it is the integral from $0$ to $1$ is that $$0<\frac1n<\frac2n<\cdots<\frac nn=1$$

We are using values $x$ between $0$ to $1$ to estimate the area under the curve for that integral range.

Comment: But why does the integral go from 0 to 1? Is it just defined this way?

Comment: Updated the answer to include information about the range.